# Rust: conversion from generic with trait bound affects trait object type

Tags: rust

I'm working on a simple opengl wrapper library in rust.

Im using [nalgebra_glm](https://crates.io/crates/nalgebra-glm) crate for the math operations. Lots of types implement `AsRef` for the access to the underlying array. I manually implemented `Uniform` for array types that match common matrix sizes like `[[T; 4]; 4]`, `[T; 16]`, `[T; 3]` and so on.

So I can obtain a new `Box<dyn Uniform>` by calling `Box::new(<nalgebra_glm matrix or vector>.as_ref().clone())` but it's unnecessarily verbose.

I wanted to create a convenience function that converts any `&[T]` which is `Clone` and `AsRef` to some type `U` that implements `Uniform` into `Vec<Box<dyn Uniform>>`. Something similar to `ToOwned` trait.

Here's what I came up with.

```rust
pub trait Uniform {
    fn bind(&self, location: GLint);
}
```

```rust
pub fn to_owned<U: Uniform + Clone, T: AsRef<U>>(uniforms: &[T]) -> Vec<Box<dyn Uniform>>
where Vec<Box<dyn Uniform>>: FromIterator<Box<U>>
{
    uniforms.into_iter()
        .map(AsRef::as_ref)
        .map(Clone::clone)
        .map(Box::new)
        .collect()
}
```

But then when I tried using this function in the following context it caused and error which I'm struggling to understand.

`perspective_matrix()` and `view_matrix()` are both of type `Mat4` and provide a `AsRef<[[f32; 4]; 4]`.

```
let common_uniforms = to_owned(&[camera.perspective_matrix(), camera.view_matrix()]);
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(dyn Uniform + 'static): Clone` is not satisfied
   --> src\main.rs:167:27
    |
167 |     let common_uniforms = to_owned(&[camera.perspective_matrix(), camera.view_matrix()]);
    |                           ^^^^^^^^ the trait `Clone` is not implemented for `(dyn Uniform + 'static)`
    |
note: required by a bound in `uniform::to_owned`
   --> src\uniform.rs:9:30
    |
9   | pub fn to_owned<U: Uniform + Clone, T: AsRef<U>>(uniforms: &[T]) -> Vec<Box<dyn Uniform>>
    |                              ^^^^^ required by this bound in `uniform::to_owned`
```

Why is `Clone` required by the resulting trait object? `clone` is only needed during operations on generic `U` and thus only `U` should implement `Clone`. Why does it have anything to do with the final trait object? I would expect that since `U` implements `Uniform` it should be possible to create a `dyn Uniform` trait object out of it.

Also I cannot require `Clone` as super trait for `Uniform` since it would make it not object safe.

I have tried explicitly casting resulting box type into trait object, adding `'static` lifetime bound but to no avail.

```rust
pub fn to_owned<U: 'static + Uniform + Clone, T: AsRef<U>>(uniforms: &[T]) -> Vec<Box<dyn Uniform>>
where Vec<Box<dyn Uniform>>: FromIterator<Box<U>>
{
    uniforms.into_iter()
        .map(AsRef::as_ref)
        .map(Clone::clone)
        .map(|uniform| Box::new(uniform) as Box<dyn Uniform>)
        .collect()
}
```

I really don't understand what's wrong with my code. It's either that I'm doing some syntactic mistake or there's deeper logical error with what I'm trying to accomplish here.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Your bits and pieces of code are really not a complete [mre], provide a dummy `camera` and the appropriate `use`s for external types (`GLint`, `Mat4`?, ...) so we can run your example, see the error for ourselves and work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is your `to_owned` function.

With `where Vec<Box<dyn Uniform>>: FromIterator<Box<U>>` you are actually hiding the real problem, causing very confusing compiler messages.

You probably added this because the compiler suggested it. But the compiler also warns that while this is what it needs, adding the `where` clause is probably not the correct solution.
With the `where` clause, instead of specifying correct bounds that make the conversion possible, you just move the problem out of the function. I agree with the compiler that this is the wrong solution.

Your second attempt is almost correct, all you are missing is that you need to remove the `where` clause:

```rust
use nalgebra_glm::Mat4;

fn perspective_matrix() -> Mat4 {
    todo!()
}

pub trait Uniform {
    fn bind(&self, location: i32);
}

impl Uniform for [[f32; 4]; 4] {
    fn bind(&self, _location: i32) {
        todo!()
    }
}

pub fn to_owned<T, U>(uniforms: &[T]) -> Vec<Box<dyn Uniform>>
where
    T: AsRef<U>,
    U: Uniform + Clone + 'static,
{
    uniforms
        .into_iter()
        .map(AsRef::as_ref)
        .map(Clone::clone)
        .map(|uniform| Box::new(uniform) as Box<dyn Uniform>)
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    let _common_uniforms = to_owned(&[perspective_matrix()]);
}
```

Also, this is how a minimal reproducible example looks like ;)